# Repeating functions inside “if”

Tags: google-sheets

I was creating a spreadsheet the other day and I stumbled across the following "problem".
I wanted to test the result of a function against a value and if that was true, display the result of the function, otherwise display a default value.

What I started doing is:

```
=if(function()="X",function(),"default value")
```

( function() being a generic name for any function)

But I thought, this way I'm adding extra load to my sheet by running this function twice. I tried looking online for a way to do the same thing by running the function only once but I couldn't find anything (or more like couldn't find the right keywords to do so).

Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't be adding load, as the function results are cached. That is, a function call with a specific set of parameters will [always return the same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022984/google-apps-script-to-summarise-data-not-updating/9023954#9023954).

If you still want to avoid calling your function several times, you could store the result of your inner function in a cell, and reference it:

```
   A                                    B
1  =if(B1 = 'X', B1, "default value")   =function()
```

Comment: Is this the same for built-in functions? I should have mentioned (I'll edit my post now) that I used "function()" as a generic name for any function.

Comment: If I've understood correctly: Yes. But only as long as the parameter values have not changed. So if `function()` is in fact `=SUM(C1:C)`, the result is cached as long as the values in column `C` have not changed.